# SDL C++ Collision on multiple objects?

Tags: c++, collision

So I was determined to get collision working myself from online resources without asking for help & I successfully followed a tutorial on lazyfoo to get collision working but quickly realised other problems.

So I started trying to get my collision working on my player (just a rect with controls atm) but couldn't actually access the rect inside the player class, I had to initialize it in main & use that for collision which meant transferring my collision function to main (not exactly perfect).

**My question**: So my collision is limited to two rects which I dedicated to the player & a single asteroid but my idea was to create multiple asteroids coming from the top of the screen, how would I go about altering the below code to accept a vector of "asteroids". Any advice about altering my code to be better object oriented etc is more then welcome but my main problem is collision. **Please read collision carefully before posting, the specific X and Y params from the .cpp provides are hardcoded there.**

Below Code order:

- My current way of defining both player & asteroid for collision
- Collision function
- Asteroid.cpp & Player.cpp
- My new way of loading asteroids - This is what I need collision to work with

  ```
  Player aPlayer(200, 50, 50, 50);
  Asteroid oneAsteroid(200, -50, 50, 50);

  bool check_collision(SDL_Rect aPlayer, SDL_Rect oneAsteroid) {

      //The sides of the rectangles
      int leftA, leftB;
      int rightA, rightB;
      int topA, topB;
      int bottomA, bottomB;

      //Calculate the sides of rect A
      leftA = aPlayer.X;
      rightA = aPlayer.X + aPlayer.width;
      topA = aPlayer.Y;
      bottomA = aPlayer.Y + aPlayer.height;

      //Calculate the sides of rect B
      leftB = oneAsteroid.X;
      rightB = oneAsteroid.X + oneAsteroid.width;
      topB = oneAsteroid.Y;
      bottomB = oneAsteroid.Y + oneAsteroid.height;


      if (bottomA <= topB)
      {
          return false;
      }

      if (topA >= bottomB)
      {
          return false;
      }

      if (rightA <= leftB)
      {
          return false;
      }

      if (leftA >= rightB)
      {
          return false;
      }

      //If none of the sides from A are outside B
      return true;
  }

  #include "asteroids.h"

  Asteroid::Asteroid()
  {


  }

  Asteroid::~Asteroid()
  {


  }

  Asteroid::Asteroid(int x, int y, int w, int h)
  {
      X = x; Y = y; width = w; height = h;
      //SDL_LogMessage(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_INFO, "Square Constructed with Param(&p)", this);

  }

  void Asteroid::Render(SDL_Renderer * aRenderer)
  {
      printf("");
      SDL_Rect* aAsteroid = new SDL_Rect();
      aAsteroid->x = X; aAsteroid->y = Y; aAsteroid->w = width; aAsteroid->h = height;
      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(aRenderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
      SDL_RenderFillRect(aRenderer, aAsteroid);

  }

  void Asteroid::Init()
  {
      velocity.X = 0;
      velocity.Y = 5;

  }

  void Asteroid::Update()
  {
      Y = Y + velocity.Y;
  //  printf("%d \n", Astero);
      if (Y > 650) {
          Y = -50;
      }

  }

  #include "Player.h"
  #include "asteroids.h"

  using namespace std;

  Player::Player()
  {
  }

  Player::~Player()
  {
      SDL_LogMessage(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_INFO, "Player Destroyed (&p)", this);
  }

  Player::Player(int x, int y, int w, int h)
  {
      X = x; Y = y; width = w; height = h;
      //SDL_LogMessage(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_INFO, "Square Constructed with Param(&p)", this);

  }

  void Player::Init()
  {
      velocity.X = 10;
      velocity.Y = 10;
  }

  void Player::Update()
  {
      Y = Y + floorStart;

      if (X < 0) {
          X = 0;
      }

      if (KEY_RIGHT == true) {
          X++;
      }

      if (X > SCREEN_WIDTH - 50) {
          X = SCREEN_WIDTH - 50;
      }

      if (Y > SCREEN_HEIGHT - 100) {
          Y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 100;
      }

      if (KEY_LEFT == true) {
          X--;
      }


  }

  void Player::Input(SDL_Event event)
  {


      if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && event.key.repeat == NULL)
      {
          if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LEFT) {
              KEY_LEFT = true;
          }
          else {
              KEY_LEFT = false;
          }

          if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RIGHT) {
              KEY_RIGHT = true;
          }
          else {
              KEY_RIGHT = false;
          }
      }

      if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP && event.key.repeat == NULL) {
          if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LEFT) {
              KEY_LEFT = false;
          }
          if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RIGHT) {
              KEY_RIGHT = false;
          }

      }
  }

  void Player::Render(SDL_Renderer * aRenderer)
  {
      SDL_Rect* thePlayer = new SDL_Rect;
      thePlayer->x = X; thePlayer->y = Y; thePlayer->w = width; thePlayer->h = height;
      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(aRenderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
      SDL_RenderFillRect(aRenderer, thePlayer);
      //SDL_LogMessage(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_INFO, "Rendering (&p)", this);
  }
  ```

  What I need collision to work with, a vector of asteroids:

  ```
  std::vector<Asteroid*> asteroidList;
  asteroidList.push_back(new Asteroid(150, 350, 50, 50));
  asteroidList.push_back(new Asteroid(70, 120, 125, 125));
  ```

  The function to check collision in main.cpp

  ```
  if (check_collision(aPlayer.thePlayer, oneAsteroid.aAsteroid)) {
              printf("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
  }
  ```

And lastly, how would I go about rendering the array of asteroids?

Comment: Just call `check_collision` for each item in vector of asteroids?

Comment: Check the function again, it's specifically coded for the single player & asteroid and requires two Rect's to be sent to it which a vector is not.

Comment: Alright, you just need to call it for each item in vector of asteroids supplying two Rects for each call.

Comment: I appreciate the comments but I already know I need to call it for each item in the vector, I just don't know how to alter my collision code to do that.

Comment: There is no need to alter `check_collision` code anyhow. Though in general this code could be improved in various ways, for example right now it leaks all the memory allocated with `new`.

Comment: I have a separate function for deallocating memory which I didn't include in the post